# Modified .Bashrc file unable to boot ubuntu

Tags: boot, 18.04, dual-boot, grub2, bash

I just update my .bashrc file in ubuntu to insert enviroment,

after i reboot my pc i manage to show GRUB dual boot menu and when i choose ubuntu i gave me black screen,
like this

[blank screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ktLa3.jpg)

can someone help to restore my ubuntu?

thanks, for your time!

Comment: Does this black screen occur BEFORE or AFTER you log in?

Comment: Can you launch any TTY terminals by pressing Ctrl+Alt+Fkeys ?

Comment: hey @heynnema it appears before login after i choose ubuntu it turns to blackscreen

Comment: hey @Puspam do you mean after i choose ubuntu i try to launch terminal?

Comment: See https://askubuntu.com/questions/162075/my-computer-boots-to-a-black-screen-what-options-do-i-have-to-fix-it and https://wiki.ubuntu.com/X/Troubleshooting/BlankScreen

Comment: When the blank screen appears, press Ctrl+Alt+F3. You will get a terminal which asks for `login`. Can you get that?